# How to count the element that fulfill a condition

Tags: java, vector, count

I want to count one time the element v[i] as long as it fulfill the condition.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "count v[i]" ?

Answer (score 2):

Create a counter variable before you begin the loop and increment onto it after the condition fulfills:

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
    if((v[i] - p) < 3 ){
        count++;
        p = i;
    }  
}
```

Comment: I want to hold that v[i] for which that condition fulfills.So,i want to count v[i] one time.If i use a counter,it will increase every time the condition is available (every time v[i] - p < 3).I want to know for how many v[i] ( with i from 0 -> m ) the condition v[i] - p < 3 is true.

Comment: Then add each `i` that you've already counted to a hash table or dictionary.  The hash table will only take unique values, so you have to see if it already exists in the hash table before adding the next `i` to it.  When you are done looping, just retrieve the count of the number of items you have in the hash table.